# Is it possible to execute update query in android using JDBC driver

Tags: java, android

I am trying to execute update query in android using JDBC Driver, but nothing is happening however insert query is working properly.

Comment: See: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15853566/295004)

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to MySQL or any remote database from android but it is not recommended at all. 
The recommended way is to write a simple web service that connects your android app and database engine.
You can use PHP (the simplest way) to write web service. Data will be sent to the database via web service and the result can be retrieved in response.

Comment: But my requirement is to connect MySql database only using JDBC Driver